# Issue with NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

I'm having problems with a NullPointerException.

I was doing the debugging and the element is not null, I have the problem in the first IF and I can not see what the problem is. I thought that happened when the state of the element was null, but I tried to fix it and it did not work

// Update: The problem is when I Check the status

```
for (Items item : master.getItems()) {
try {
    if (item.getCompany_status().equals("active") || item.getCompany_status().equals("open")) {

if (item.getAddress_snippet() == null) {
    cont2++;
    Company c = new Company(item.getTitle(), "");                            
    arrayCompany.add(c);
}else {
    cont2++;
    Company c = new Company(item.getTitle(), item.getAddress_snippet());                                 
    arrayCompany.add(c);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: `item.getAddress_snippet().equals(null)` is almost certainly wrong. Use `==` to compare to `null`

Comment: if  `getAddress_snippet()` in `item.getAddress_snippet().equals(null)` returns null, the call .equals() won't work because null isn't an object with methods. You'll need to write `item.getAddress_snippet() == null`

Comment: This is a NPE, so you missed the actual variable being null. With a [mcve] or at least the stacktrace, we could confirm what you missed. Please [edit] your question with the information. And FYI, from [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) you can read "_For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend to make the equals the other way:

Instead of:

```
item.getCompany_status().equals("active")
```

Do:

```
"active".equals(item.getCompany_status())
```

This way, at runtime, if the status is null, it won't crash as it first checks the string.

It is more likely to have `"value".equals(null)` than `null.equals("value")` as **you can't call `.equals()` from a null object**.

Comment: Thank you so much, i already fixed that, but the problem is in the first IF (item.getCompany_Status())

Comment: @R.Sanchez Check my edit!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! this solved my problem!!!!

Comment: @R.Sanchez I'm glad it helped, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This is Strongly type so it `tem.getCompany_status()` is null , it gives null pointer exception,

```
item.getCompany_status().equals("active") || 
item.getCompany_status().equals("open")
```

So, use

```
"active".equals(item.getCompany_status()) || 
"open".equals(item.getCompany_status())
```